# Python regular expression again - match url part II

Tags: python, regex

Ok. I get regexp from [here](http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls) (only WWW links, second version). Everything is fine, except one thing, it parse BBCode too.

**Regexp**

```
(?i)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))
```

**What fails**

[img]http://example.foo/something.png[/img]

When I apply regexp I get http://example.foo/something.png[/img and that's fail. :P Any regexp guru there?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to add in the ability for it to accept a URL surrounded by the '[img]' tags? i.e. "http://example.foo/something.png" works but "[img]http://example.foo/something.png[/img"] fails?

Comment: Exactly. I'm parsing user input. Sometimes they use BB code. I want to get all links ("naked" (without BB code) and surrounded with BB code). Edit: and that regexp match too much, http://example.foo/something.png[/img instead of http://example.foo/something.png.

Comment: Well there is a problem in that `[` and `]` are reserved characters and are permitted in URI's. I would use a BBCode library to parse out BBCode first and then look for URLs with the regex, otherwise if you reject the square brackets, you could potentially reject valid URIs.

Comment: Saying this though, it seems that square brackets are only valid in certain places in the URI and it may be possible to re-write the regex aaccordingly (see [this question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/)) ...

Comment: I did as you suggested. BB code strip -> match all links, iterate them and change in original value. Works great. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a little rough, but try this:

```
$preg = "%(?:https?://|www\d{0,3}.)(?:[\/A-Za-z0-9-_.]+(?!(?:<|\[/([A-Za-z0-9])+?\1)))%";
```

I've tested it and it should work as expected if I understood your question correctly.